# How to truncate the text between the children of a flexbox child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I understand how to truncate the text which is wrapped inside a flex child however this particular case seems a bit complicated.

[image]

The desired behaviour is that the text between the two blue blocks should get truncated to keep them inside the red border.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.container .left {
    min-width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.left .label {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.left .block {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container .right {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right .block {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    
    <div class="label">
      Is this the real life?
    </div>
    
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When adding "display: flex" to the class "left" it works. But you don't want to do that, right? Adding "flex-shrink: 0" to your class "block" keeps them squared btw.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? Basically i added `flexbox` property for left and right `div`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-end;
    min-width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.label {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.block {
    background-color: blue;
}

.right {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

.right .block {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
    
    <div class="label">
      Is this the real life?
    </div>
    
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="right">
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That would spoil a lot of things in my real world case but if nothing else works then it can be thought of as the last option

Comment: I did not get it, this is well known solution. What is your real world case then?